# Copying contents of a folder via SCP results in `scp: error: unexpected filename: .`

Tags: shell-script, scripting, scp, remote, file-transfer

I was using a script to copy the contents of a folder via SCP, without copying the folder itself. Something like this:

```
scp -i id_rsa -P "$PORT" -r "$HOST:/folder1/folder2/." "backup"
```

(I'm not able to use `*` because I want to include dot files, too.)

This has recently stopped working and I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> scp: error: unexpected filename: .
> ```

I think the cause for this are [these changes](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/4667d15cf6214d4cb6b8c347f13864ca8c72002e#diff-e958952155bec91aa3a85f32af5428e5R1086) to SCP from November 2018.

Does this mean I'm no longer able to copy contents of a folder via SCP without copying the folder itself?

Comment: Why not just use `rsync` instead? It does exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your interpretation is correct. It was probably an undocumented feature, removed from the undocumented api (see the web archive of the [protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20141204121614/https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works)). One workaround is for you to create a symbolic link in the backup directory before the copy.

```
ln -s . folder2
```